# Select odd items in SP List, selectRowByIndex

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select odd items in SharePoint list using the following:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i< ctx.ListData.Row.length ; i++){
if(parseInt(ctx.ListData.Row[i].ID % 2 !==0)){
SelectRowByIndex(ctx, i, true); 
}
}
```

But when the `SelectRowByIndex(ctx, i, true);`  is executed, it's telling me `undefined` so I tried also settings the selected column using `SelectRowByIndex(ctx, 3, true);` to make sure my code is working, but it's giving me the same result, why is this function not working?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i< ctx.ListData.Row.length ; i++){
    if((ctx.ListData.Row[i].ID) %2 !== 0) {
        SelectRowByIndex(ctx, i, true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nadeem, thanks for your answer, the same exact method is not working, my problem is not with the if condition, the line: `SelectRowByIndex(ctx, i, true);` doesn't work, even if I write the index static like `SelectRowByIndex(ctx, 0, true);` , it's always `undefined`

Comment: Interesting, works fine for me in SP 2013 on premise.

Comment: I am using O365 developer site.